# javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR What that means?

Tags: xml, wsdl

I have the follow exception and I don't undestand what that mean. Someone can help me?

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://ecmwebd.net.bradesco.com.br:80/gccn_integracaofilenetceimagem_ws/services/IntegracaoFileNetCEImagem'.: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: the markup in the document following the root element must be properly formed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometime this kind of error happens due to bad .wsdl files or .wsdl page link not directly getting saved into the project.
So follow steps below- it might look funny but solved my issue...

> 1. Open web service description in browser
> 2. Save that description in .xml document
> 3. Now, change the .xml file into .wsdl file by just changing its extension type to .wsdl
> 4. Save it locally
> 5. Now Open SOAP-UI and browse for the stored .wsdl file
> 6. You are ready to get it opened web service requests successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you generated the code from the WSDL file and the url has the alias and not the IP can cause some issues if you're running in a localhost.

My web service was published in 9080 with a domain alias provided by the web sphere 
My web application was publish in 9081 in another docker container and I had this error
After I put the IP instead of the Domain address to generate the client package started to work
**Environment**
Primefaces 6.2

- JSF 2.2
- Websphere 8.5
- JAX-WS SOAP